# Selector de años Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

de nuevo preguntando.
Algo extraño pasa con este código.

Se trata de sumar y restar los años a partir del año actual.....

En un Input, coloco el año actual y mediante la llamada a las funciones 'adelante' y 'atras' sumo ó resto el valor del Input, bueno pues no.

cuando resto, lo hace bien...2022-1=2021

cuando sumo hace esto 2022+1=**20221**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var hoy= new Date();
var year= hoy.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('anno').value=year

    
}); 

function adelante(){
    document.getElementById('anno').value=document.getElementById('anno').value+1
    }
  
function atras(){
    document.getElementById('anno').value=document.getElementById('anno').value-1
}
```

```html
 

<input type="text" id="anno"> 
<br><br>
<button onclick="adelante()">Sumar año</button>  

<button onclick="atras()">Restar año</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta agregar el `parseInt()` en los datos que recuperas del **input** para que los valores recuperados sean tratados como números enteros en lugar de *string*.

De este modo:

```
document.getElementById('anno').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('anno').value) + 1
```

También podrias usar el signo + ([operador unario](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)) delante del valor recuperado por javascript, aunque es una sintaxis no es tan usada, para que sea interpretado como número (da igual si es entero como con decimales). Por ejemplo así:

```
document.getElementById('anno').value = +(document.getElementById('anno').value) + 1
```

Por defecto javascript recupera los números como *string* y debes decirle explícitamente que son números enteros mediante [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) o bien si son con decimales mediante [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), o bien lo dicho del [operador unario](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

En cuanto a el **porque** cuando restabas te funcionaba y cuando sumabas no, deduzco que es debido a que **el signo de sumar se usa también para concatenar cadenas** (*string*), y en ese caso identificaba el primer operando como cadena, dándole preferencia a la concatenación en lugar de la suma. En cambio, **el signo de resta seguramente solo se usa para números**, por lo tanto internamente debe forzar su conversión a números si puede, y en ese caso funciona bien aparéntemente. Si no puede convertirlos a números entonces muestra un `NaN` como respuesta de la operación.

Aqui dejo un snippet de ejemplo para que lo ejecutes con las tres formas y veas que ahora sí que funciona bien (excepto la última, donde no aplico ni el *parseInt* ni el uso del signo *+* sobre el valor recuperado en javascript):

```js
// con parseInt
function adelante() {
  document.getElementById('anno').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('anno').value) + 1
}

function atras() {
  document.getElementById('anno').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('anno').value) - 1
}
// con + (plus)
function adelante_plus() {
  document.getElementById('anno_plus').value = +(document.getElementById('anno_plus').value) + 1  
}

function atras_plus() {
  document.getElementById('anno_plus').value = +(document.getElementById('anno_plus').value) - 1
}

// con strings
function adelante_string() {
  document.getElementById('anno_string').value = document.getElementById('anno_string').value + 1
}

function atras_string() {
  document.getElementById('anno_string').value = document.getElementById('anno_string').value - 1
}
```

```html
<h3>
Con parseInt (número entero)
</h3>
<input id="anno" value="2022">
<input type="button" onclick="adelante()" value="Adelante">
<input type="button" onclick="atras()" value="Atrás">
<h3>
Con operador unario <b>+</b> (número entero o decimal)
</h3>
<input id="anno_plus" value="2022">
<input type="button" onclick="adelante_plus()" value="Adelante">
<input type="button" onclick="atras_plus()" value="Atrás">
<h3>
Sin parseInt ni operador unario (string)
</h3>
<input id="anno_string" value="2022">
<input type="button" onclick="adelante_string()" value="Adelante">
<input type="button" onclick="atras_string()" value="Atrás">
```